# Ruby Curly Brackets for "set" value

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between these two variations in Ruby

```
set: example1, "/random/string"
```

and

```
set: example2, -> {"random/string"}
```

Do they both have the same effect?

Comment: Could you provide some context? The syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although they look superficially similar they're actually two completely different things.

The first is a simple string, the second is a `Proc` which *returns* a string. Many methods in the Ruby world take both, the Proc version is a way of deferring evaluation of something until if and when it's needed.

The `-> { ... }` notation is shorthand for `lambda { ... }`, it's called the *stabby-lambda* operator.

Comment: To me, they both look like `SyntaxError`s, so they are exactly equivalent in that sense.

Comment: @JörgWMittag One person's line noise is another's code.